# Spark Cassandra connector Update Only if exists

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

Using Spark Cassandra Connector, I have a case where i want to use UPDATE IF EXISTS and if does not exist in table then ignore.

In the [Cassandra documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/update_r.html) we have this condition in Cassandra 2.0.7 and later, you can conditionally update columns using IF or IF EXISTS.

> Add IF EXISTS to the command to ensure that the operation is not performed if the specified row does not exist:
>
> UPDATE cycling.cyclist_id SET age = 28 WHERE lastname = 'WELTEN' and firstname = 'Bram' IF EXISTS;

However, it's unclear to me if this can be done in the Spark Cassandra Connector. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is ? Have you tried it ? The connector executes CQL queries thus it should be able to interpret any syntaxically correct query.

Comment: My problem set is two large data set where data has to be pulled by joining and i want to avoid joining the two data set.
The workaround i am trying is to create a temp table and insert first filtered dataset and then update with the same key if only exists that will avoid joining and can utilise Cassandra capability.
I have got the info from Andrew Mills
Looks like it is not something that can be done right now but it is an open issue.

https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-386 

P.S. I have a workaround but want to see if i can optimise it using spark-cassandra

Comment: And what does your question have to do with joining ? You want to perform updates so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is not something that can be done right now but it is an open issue.

https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-386 - Answered by Andrew Mills